# Updating value when overriding enter press

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have page when I have input and a button.

```
<div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Enter test</span>
        <input type="Text" class="form-control" data-bind="value:Test, event: { keypress: searchKeyboardCmd}" required  />
    </div>
</div>
<button data-bind=' event:{click:foo}' class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

and my code:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.Test = ko.observable();
    self.data = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.DeviceId = ko.observable();
    self.number = ko.observable(1);
    self.MeUser = ko.observable(true);
    self.searchKeyboardCmd = function (data, event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13)
            alert("Znalazlem enter " + ko.toJSON(self));
        return true;
    };
    self.foo = function () {
        alert("foo");
    }        
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

});

And I have problems with my code. I catch enter with this code:

```
        self.searchKeyboardCmd = function (data, event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13)
            alert("Znalazlem enter " + ko.toJSON(self));
        return true;
    };
```

It's catches perfectly but binded object is updated after calling alert. So in the first enter I null in value Test. After second enter I have first value and so on. Can anyone suggest me how to modify this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the event is executed before the `blur` event (which is when the value is updated. You can make sure the update gets updated after every keystroke by adding `valueupdate: 'afterkeydown'` to the input:

```
<div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Enter test</span>
        <input type="Text" class="form-control" 
               data-bind="valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', value:Test, event: { keypress: searchKeyboardCmd}" required  />
    </div>
</div>
<button data-bind=' event:{click:foo}' class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```